# repository self checkout before extending template in pipelne.yml

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have pipeline.yml which is stored in repo - buildresources and it also have resources.json file

- buildresources repo

  - pipeline.yml
  - resources.json

now I want to pass resources.json in following pipeline.yml which further extends template in other repo,how do I pass the resources.json path in buildresources repo to deploy-iac.yml in AzureIacPoC/AzureIacPoc repo

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: cloud-iac # The name used to reference this repository in the checkout step
    type: git    
    name: AzureIacPoC/AzureIacPoc
    ref: refs/heads/features/azure

trigger:
  branches:
    include: [features/*, master]



extends:
  template: deploy-iac.yml@cloud-iac
  parameters:
    resourceGroupName: 'anuj-test-automation'
    location: 'Canada Central'
    csmfile: resources.json
    environment: 'sandbox'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: AnotherRepoName
    type: git
    name: YourProjectName/AnotherRepoName
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: AnotherRepoName
- script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```